# Google Analytics Event track on page load

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to track pageviews on certain types of pages across multiple websites with different url structures (which rules out using a RegEx to segment a common section of the URLs). Is it possible to track page loads with an event script? Would it be used as an onLoad event?

Comment: I don't understand why you would track page loads as an event. Have you considered custom dimensions? 
Obviously if you could provide more info on what you are trying to achive that may clarify.

Comment: I'm trying to find a uniform way to track this page subset across client websites all with different URL structure. All of our clients have a unique page for every vehicle in inventory, but the URL structure may differ (example: /inventory/ or /vehicles/). I could theoretically install an event that on each client inventory page that shows Category/Action/Label as "Vehicles"/"View"/New|Used.

Further complicating matters: we're using a 3rd party tool (Supermetrics) to collect this data and custom dimensions aren't able to be tracked (however events are).

Comment: You could pass custom page paths to your tracking call that unfies the url scheme in the reports (if you can set event names then surely you can also generate custom page paths). About the only disadvantage is that you cannot use inpage analysis in GA (and that is really crappy in any case, so not a big loss).

Answer (score 0):

You CAN utilize regex to accomplish this, though it does depend on how many rules you have.

Example if you want to include these two urls:

```
www.google.com/inventory/example
www.microsoft.com/vehicle/example2
```

you can use

```
.*(\/inventory\/|\/vehicle\/).*
```

Another option is to use Google Data Studio and create a calculated field based on the "page" dimension and filter/group using [CASE function](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724?hl=en).